# InVision : How to export or record or convert prototype to video / gif in InVision?

Tags: export, gif, video, prototyping

I am using InVision for prototyping online. I am done with designing. Now I want to export this interactions as video or gif to show others or to upload in social media.

Can anyone help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a screen recording tool. Kap is free, or you can use Quicktime, Gif Brawery 3, ScreenFlow (commercial)...

With these software you can record a portion of your screen and export video/gif to share online. I personally use both screenflow and kap based on the animation duration/quality i want.

Answer (score 0):

**[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/)** can record screen into GIF